# Select a subgroup of records by one distinct column

Tags: sql, t-sql, unique, distinct

Sorry if this has been answered before, but all the related questions didn't quite seem to match my purpose.

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID  POSS_PHONE    CELL_FLAG
=======================
1   111-111-1111  0
2   222-222-2222  0
2   333-333-3333  1
3   444-444-4444  1
```

I want to select only distinct ID values for an insert, but I don't care which specific ID gets pulled out of the duplicates.

For Example(a valid SELECT would be):

```
1   111-111-1111  0
2   222-222-2222  0
3   444-444-4444  1
```

Before I had the CELL_FLAG column, I was just using an aggregate function as so:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(POSS_PHONE)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ID
```

But I can't do:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(POSS_PHONE), MAX(CELL_FLAG)...
```

because I would lose integrity within the row, correct?

I've seen some similar examples using CTEs, but once again, nothing that quite fit.

So maybe this is solvable by a CTE or some type of self-join subquery?  I'm at a block right now, so I can't see any other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get your aggregation in a subquery and join to it:

```
SELECT a.ID, sub.Poss_Phone, CELL_FLAG
FROM TableA as a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(POSS_PHONE) as [Poss_Phone]
            FROM TableA
            GROUP BY ID) Sub
    ON Sub.ID = a.ID and SUB.Poss_Phone = A.Poss_Phone
```

This will keep integrity between your non-aggregated fields but still give you the `MAX(Poss_Phone)` per `ID`.

Comment: I literally JUST came across that and was coming back here to post.  +1

Comment: @Joe - subqueries are very handy for stuff like this.

Comment: I hate how obvious it seems after the fact when I spent over an hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: @joe - sometimes you need to step back to see the issue completely.